# Percentage whiteness of UIImage

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Good way to calculate ‘brightness’ of UIImage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3992790/good-way-to-calculate-brightness-of-uiimage)

For a UIImage how can you determine the percentage whiteness of the whole image?

cheers

Comment: That depends on what you mean by whiteness. % of pixels that are pure white? Average lightness of the image after converting it to grayscale?

Comment: I think average lightness 0% white to 100% black (something like that)

Comment: What exactly do you mean? I still don't get what you are asking. Do you mean the % of pixels that are white or the average saturation of the image (i.e. if you take a grayscale and get the average value of each pixel)?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your definition of 'whiteness', you may be able to simply draw the image to a 1x1 `CGBitmapContextRef`, then check the whiteness of that single pixel.